# PHP session_start() not working correctly (?)

Tags: php

So I'm having a bit of a trouble here with sessions.

For example,

I have 3 pages, `login.php`, `main_admin.php` and `main_client.php`

If the client enters the website they will go to `main_client.php`, but if I change the link to `main_admin.php` it will still enter with the session of the client.

Is there any way i can remove this?

I have the `session_start()` function call on every page.

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    if (!isset($_SESSION['login']))
        header("Location: login.php?oper=ins&perm=1");
?>
```

**It is solved! Thank you MCMXCII for the post edit and B. Desai for the solution.**

Comment: write `exit();` after `header` function

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your problem.  Can you clarify?

Comment: Thank you B. Dessai, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

If i understand what you want to achieve, do something like that:

```
<?php 

 $session_start();

 if ( ! isset($_SESSION['login']))
      header("Location: login.php?oper=ins&perm=1");

 if ( ! isset($_SESSION['isAdmin']))
      header("Location: login.php?oper=ins&perm=1");

 ?>
```